# IE 11 not opening bing or google result links

Tags: internet-explorer

I have IE 11 on windows 7. When I go to bing.com and search I get the results as normally. The problem is the result links are not clickable. It sometimes happen for google.com also. Chrome works fine but IE does not. I have reset the browser several time and scanned for malware with malwarebyte, tdskiller etc. Nothing.

Can anyone advice me?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is for this site since its not code related. With that said I suggest clearing your browsers cache because I'm pretty confident that issue is on your machine and not with Google or MS.

Answer (score 0):

Probably long fixed but I found IE11 (On windows 7) failed for me with any google searches until the black bar mysteriously manages to load.

Try adding /?noj=0 to the end of your google homepage and see if that works. (It loads the google page, but with the black bar of options at the top)